# asp.net/sql get everything in the string before the "-" and put it into a different string

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

Basically I have got two things i am passing from a command argument

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbEditDetails" Text="Edit..." runat="server" CommandName="EditDetails" CssClass="EditAdults" CommandArgument=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "number_slept") & "-" & DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "booking_ref")  %>></asp:LinkButton>
```

I need to grab the `number_slept` which is everything before the `-` and put it into another string and then grab the `booking_ref` which is after the `-` and put that into a string

Here's what I've got

```
Dim strPassedString = e.CommandArgument

Dim NumberSlept = This will be the passed number slept

Dim BookingRef = This will be the passed booking ref
```

I'm not sure how to split the command argument

Is it possible?

Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

C#, but you get the idea...

```
string numberSlept = e.CommandArgument.Split('-')[0];
string bookingRef = e.CommandArgument.Split('-')[1];
```